# Getting a variable end of year date and value from MS Access table using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, max, summary

I have some data is that is daily (day on day) closing figures for a tracked supply and is in one MS Access table that has 2 columns - Dates (the date), PXLast(the day's closing figure)).
 I have daily data from Jan 1991 to Aug 2013 and I wanted to get the percentage change of PXLast at every year end compared to last year year end as follows:

Year  | Percentage Change of PXLast(Year on Year)

1991 | 15.2%
1992 | 9.2%

The year end date varies (not always 31st ) and I am going about getting the last PXLast value by:

1.Get the max date in Dec every year: results in MyYear, MyMonth, MyDay

2.Combine it using DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth, MyDay)

3.Join the resulting query to the table and inner join on the date column

4.Get the PXLast value

```
   SELECT EndDates.EndDates, NSE20.PX_LAST AS LookPoint
    FROM NSE20 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DateSerial([MyYear],[MyMonth],[MyDay]) 
    AS EndDates FROM (SELECT 12 AS MyMonth, MyDay, MyYear FROM 
    (SELECT Max(Day([Dates])) AS MyDay, Year([Dates]) AS MyYear 
    FROM NSE20 WHERE (((Month([Dates]))=12)) 
     GROUP BY Year([Dates])) AS EndYearValues) 
    AS EndValueDates) 
    AS EndDates ON NSE20.Dates = EndDates.EndDates;
```

Could anyone assist me get the corresponding value using a query for previous year end

eg for 29 Dec 2006, it should show the current value and show the value for 31 Dec 2005

in the same row ie

Year | Current Year End| Previous Year End

2005 | 3449.00         | 4611.19

2006 | 9.2%            |3449.00

Any help is appreciated.

Any suggestions to a better way of doing this is very very welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have some test data in a table named [NSE20] that looks like this

```
Dates       PXLast
----------  ------
2010-07-01     131
2010-12-31     130
2011-11-12     123
2011-12-30     125
2012-01-03     127
2012-12-31     129
```

I'd start by creating a saved query in Access named [NSE20_year_ends] that identifies the year-end dates by (calendar) year:

```
SELECT Year(Dates) AS CalendarYear, Max(Dates) AS YearEndDate
FROM NSE20
GROUP BY Year(Dates)
```

That will produce

```
CalendarYear  YearEndDate
------------  -----------
        2010  2010-12-31 
        2011  2011-12-30 
        2012  2012-12-31
```

Then I'd create another saved query named [NSE20_year_end_balances] to extract the closing balances for each year:

```
SELECT NSE20_year_ends.CalendarYear, NSE20.PXLast
FROM 
    NSE20
    INNER JOIN
    NSE20_year_ends
        ON NSE20.Dates = NSE20_year_ends.YearEndDate
```

That will give us

```
CalendarYear  PXLast
------------  ------
        2010     130
        2011     125
        2012     129
```

Now we can do a self-join on that query to calculate the percentage change

```
SELECT 
    y1.CalendarYear, 
    (y1.PXLast - y0.PXLast) / y0.PXLast * 100 AS PctChange
FROM
    NSE20_year_end_balances y1
    INNER JOIN
    NSE20_year_end_balances y0
        ON y0.CalendarYear = y1.CalendarYear - 1
```

resulting in

```
CalendarYear  PctChange        
------------  -----------------
        2011  -3.84615384615385
        2012                3.2
```

Comment: I can t seem to get the self join to run

Comment: Oops, syntax error, had added a comma in the From clause, first time user of a self join.

Comment: It has worked. Its exactly what I needed! Thank you for all the help, and the lesson in self join use.